# Tomcat session does not persist for multiple tomcat pods with the Memcached session manager

Tags: session, tomcat, memcached

There are multiple pods for Tomcat, and for session management, we use Couchbase with the Memcached session manager

Pods
tomcat-0
tomcat-1
tomcat-2

"Ideally, we expect the behavior to be as follows: If I initiate the request using http://localhost:8089/ and the session is initiated by 'tomcat-0' with the session ID 'AB312C4BBD371551735C4950858E98A7.dev,' it should be considered valid for 'tomcat-1' and 'tomcat-2.' However, it is not working as expected; if the session is created by 'tomcat-0,' it is valid only for 'tomcat-0' and not for the other pods."

What am I doing wrong?
Versions: apache-tomcat-8.0.50 memcached-session-manager-1.9.5.jar memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.9.5.jar spymemcached-2.11.1.jar

`<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"  memcachedNodes="n1:localhost:11211"`
`memcachedProtocol="binary"  username="xyz"  password="xyz" />`

I have set down the pods count 3 to 1. it's working as expected the issue with mulitple pods in the terraform